# Filter gridview based on the checked value from the another gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridView. First is called "gvImage" which is the category gridview with checkbox for selection. Second GridView is called "GridView1", the Second GridView populates basing on the value selected in the First GridView, here I am able to populate the record in Second GridView only for one category checked (selected) from the First GridView, but when I check (select) multiple category from the First GridView(gvImage) then it is not populating the multiple category record in the Second GridView(GridView1). Please help me to get this, below is my Code behind:

```
 protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvImage.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
                    if (isChecked)
                    {
                        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTION1"].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                        string str = "SELECT  * FROM AllProduct WHERE PId =@PId";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PId", row.Cells[1].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
                        //this.ExecuteQuery(cmd, "SELECT");
                        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
                        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        con.Open();
                        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
                        con.Close();
                        if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    sda.Fill(dt);
                                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                            GridView1.Visible = true;
                            GridView1.Enabled = true;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                        {
                            GridView1.DataSource = null;
                            GridView1.Visible = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: please post all of your code

Comment: did you try altering your query for your 2nd grid to some like [where columnName IN ( @yourvariables) ?

Comment: @ briskovich thanks, I did not try that way. Could you please type in as I haven't experience that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you bind the second grid for each selected checkbox which will essentially always replace the data that has been bound, so that you only see the results for the last selected checkbox. You need to combine the results and bind outside the foreach

```
protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable combinedDataTable;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvImage.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
            if (isChecked)
            {
                DataTable data = //Data from database for this checkbox
                if(combinedDataTable != null)
                    combinedDataTable.Merge(data);
                else
                    combinedDataTable = data;
            }
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = combinedDataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

or even better, just collect which checkboxes are checked first, and then get the results in one query:

```
protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> selectedCheckboxes = new List<string>()
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvImage.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {   
            bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
            if (isChecked)
            {
                selectedCheckboxes.Add(row.Cells[1].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Text);
            }
        }
    }

    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTION1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    string str = "SELECT  * FROM AllProduct WHERE PId in ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    List<string> parametersNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedCheckboxes.Count; i++)
    {
        var parameterName = "@PId" + i;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, selectedCheckboxes[i]);
        parametersNames.Add(parameterName);
    }
    str += "(" + String.Join(",", parametersNames) + ")";
    str += " AND TransactionDate BETWEEN @From AND @To";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", DateTime.Parse(txtFrom.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", DateTime.Parse(txtTo.Text));
    cmd.CommandText = str;
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();
    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                GridView1.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }
    else if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ hankor, thanks. I tried your second option but throws an error says : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParemterCollection does not contain a definition for 'Select' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). It throws an error in this line : str += "(" + String.Join(",", cmd.Parameters.Select(x => x.Name)) + ")";

Comment: hankor, thanks it worked!!! but also wondering if I had to choose these records between two dates from texbox, how would I placed the query? here is the query: WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN @ From AND @ To

Comment: @Turing: not sure I understand. You can just append that to the query. I've also added that to the example above